# Gitlab Ci unable to push on a branch from runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to settup a CI/CD pipelines with Gitlab
Here is what I would like to do :

NOTE: It's a typescript project

1. unit tests && integration tests
2. promote branch dev to branch integration
3. Build docker image from branch integration
4. deploy to integration env

Here is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` I am using (i:

```
stages:
  - test
  - promote
  - build
  - deploy
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
test:
  image: node
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - yarn
  script:
    - yarn test
promote:
  image: node
  stage: promote
  only:
    - dev
  script:
    - git push origin HEAD:integration
build
  image: node
  stage: build
  only: 
    - integration
  script: 
    - echo "build docker image from integration"
deploy:
  image: node
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - integration
  script:
    - echo "deploy integration"
```

My problem is that this line `git push origin HEAD:integration` can not be done from the gitlab runner, here is the output console :

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.1.0 (c1ecf97f)
  on RUNNER (ce8757c9)
Using Docker executor with image node ...
Using docker image sha256:fb8322a7cefdf2b3ba1c15218187bb65f9d4d4ab4e27dc3a91bb4eba38964429 for predefined container...
Pulling docker image node ...
Using docker image node ID=sha256:c1d02ac1d9b4de08d3a39fdacde10427d1c4d8505172d31dd2b4ef78048559f8 for build container...
Running on runner-ce8757c9-project-907-concurrent-0 via VERD842...
Fetching changes...
Removing node_modules/
HEAD is now at 63cccc5 update ci - dev
From https://gitlab.mycompany.com/project1/ci-demo
   63cccc5..98d347e  dev        -> origin/dev
Checking out 98d347e5 as dev...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default...
Successfully extracted cache
$ git push origin HEAD:integration
remote: You are not allowed to upload code for this project.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab.mycompany.com/project1/ci-democi-demo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I have read the docs, and some example, but I cant figure out on how to make this work ? 
Should I create a user  `gitlab-ci-token` ? 
Should I do branch promotion in a `bash` script ?

Feel free to give me any feedback on the pipeline I try to do...

Regards

Comment: 1. have you provided git credentials to this pipeline?


2. is git credentials right ?


3. What does git debugging says when GIT_TRACING=2 and GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 are set ?


4. Is the remote branch you are trying to push a protected one ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To push to a repo from within a Gitlab CI runner you need to use a user that has push access to the branch you want to push to. We use the following set-up to accomplish this (we let Gitlab CI tag releases and push them).

1. Create a **new Gitlab user** called **`gitlab-ci`**
2. [Create a **SSH key-pair**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair) and add the **public key** to the [gitlab-ci user's SSH keys in Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html)
3. Give the gitlab-ci user [**push access to your repo**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/index.html#add-a-user) (developer role)
4. Add the content of the **private-key** as a [**CI/CD secret variable**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#secret-variables) called **`SSH_PRIVATE_KEY**`

This way the private key will be available in CI jobs, next the first part of my CI job looks like this:

```
script:
    # Install ssh-agent through openssh-client if not present
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -qy && apt-get install openssh-client -qqy )'
    # Add the private key to this user
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY") && mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    # Docker specific settings
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    # Config git to avoid first usage questions. Set the identity
    - git config --global user.email "noreply@example.com" && git config --global user.name "Gitlab CI"
    # 
    # Do Git stuff, for example:
    #
    - git checkout $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - git tag my-release-1.0
    - git push -u origin my-release-1.0
```

**Big fat disclaimer**: Only use this in Gitlab CI runner setups that are disposed of, you are distributing private SSH keys with potential access to your repo so you must use this carefully.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 
This worked for me, and I used a script here : https://github.com/IlyaSemenov/gitlab-ci-git-push

Comment: Creating a separate user is a bit of a hack, Gitlab has a deploy key system by which you can enable push access via without having a dummy user.

Comment: Is there a way to use a different username instead of gitlab-ci?

Comment: Sure, it doesn't matter what you call the user. It is identified by the key.

Comment: @Ced [The documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#deploy-keys)  is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

try with this solution :
[Gitlab runner failing -urgent](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-runner-failing-urgent/8180/2)

Open and edit `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file.

and then add this code

```
extra_hosts = [“yourhostname:youripddress”]
```

for example file :

```
[[runners]]
name = "co1"
url = "http://co1/ci"
token = “1ccc03308b71a1c9a10640326adf1a"
executor = “docker”
[runners.docker]
tls_verify = false
image = “co1:5000/pub/pub"
privileged = false
disable_cache = false
volumes = [”/cache”]
shm_size = 0
extra_hosts = [“co1:192.168.176.137”]
[runners.cache]
```

Comment: It doesn't. This is used for hostname resolution.