# gitlab pipeline triggering git commit, git authentication

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We are using gitlab pipeline's to build our application. When building, a version number is incremented, committed and pushed. That is done inside the pipeline.

However when when the pipeline pushes it isn't logged in as a git user and the git message `Please tell me who you are` appears.

How can we manage to have an automated user like `GITLAB_CI` to make the commit / push to our repository .

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html This isn't anonymous but can be passed as a variable to your push

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523286/gitlab-ci-unable-to-push-on-a-branch-from-runner